# Test private method of controller with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate!

  private
  def authenticate!
    session_token = request.env["HTTP_SESSIONTOKEN"]
    @current_user = User.where(session_token: session_token).first unless session_token.blank?
    unless @current_user
      return render_json({message: "ERROR: Invalid Session"})
    end
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user
  end 
end
```

I am testing session_controller which inherits base_controller

```
before do 
    post :create, {email: "raj@gmail.com", user_name: "raj",password: "raj"}
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    @session_token = body["session_token"]
end

   describe "PUT #edit_email" do
    context "if new email already exist" do
      it "should return with a error message" do
        put :edit_email, {email: "raj@gmail.com", new_email: "ravi@gmail.com", password: "raj"}
        body = JSON.parse(response.body)
        expect(body["message"]).to eq("email already exist")
      end
    end
  end
```

I am new to rspec and here I am confused about calling private authenticate method with session_token.
How to call private method of controller and pass header.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your env variable like following:

```
request.env['HTTP_SESSIONTOKEN'] = "..."
```

For testing your private method:

```
controller.instance_eval{ authenticate }.should eql ...
```

Comment: Would using `#__send__` rather than `#instance_eval` be better?

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby/Rails and OOP in general private methods **should not** be tested. You should test the interface, not the implementation of private method.

Implementation could be changed with time - but the interface it provides would (most likely) not.

Comment: Actually you should also test private methods but only in the unit tests. You want to know how they behave in different situations. Something which is almost impossible in integration tests. However you are right that private methods shouldn't be tested but rather the interface in **integration tests**.